# Aysynchronous methods, blocks, and GCD, having trouble understanding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I have the following piece of code which uses the ALAssets library to store the users photo albums an array so it could populate them in a table like the photos app:

```
- (void) loadAlbums
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [[self activityIndicator] startAnimating];

    [[self library] enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if (group == nil)
        {
            [[self activityIndicator] stopAnimating]; 
            [[self tableView] reloadData];

            return;
        }

        [[self albums] addObject:group];
    }
    failureBlock:^(NSError *error) 
    {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Album Error: %@", [error description]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }];

    [pool release];
}
```

From the best of my understanding, `enumerateGroupsWithTypes` is an asynchronous method, which means it runs on its own thread. However the block parameter runs on the main thread.
With the code up top, I'm having a problem with my activity indicator. When the `viewcontroller` housing this method runs the first time, the `activityindicator` works fine, however if I pop the `viewcontroller` off the stack (ie push the back button) and reload it again, the activity indicator does not appear (despite me playing around with `isHidden` etc.). So I have some questions:

1) Anyone have any insight into what the problem could be with the activity indicator?

2) Aside from using `[NSThread sleepWithDuration]` and `NSTimer`, what is the best way to simulate a slow loading time without having to create a photo album with a ton of pictures?

3) If it does take a while to load the photos, will the UI of my app be blocked, or will the user still be able to interact with it? Since it's running on a separate thread it seems like it should, but I'm not really sure.

UPDATE: Any ideas or resources on how to get better with this? I've read Apple's thread programming and concurrency guys and watched a lot of the WWDC videos, yet I still have trouble grasping how to handle absolutely simple situations like this where I'm just trying to not block the UI from the user.

Comment: Why do you think the enumeration happens asynchronously? I don't see any indication of that in the documentation for the method.

Comment: @kevin ballard - it says in the docs "This method is asynchronous."

Comment: Huh, we must be looking at different versions of the docs. You're right, the [current docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722-CH1-SW2) does say that.

Comment: Have you verified that the block is, in fact, executing on the main thread? I don't see a guarantee of that in the docs.

Comment: @kevin ballard - Yes I have using NSLog(@"On main thread : %d",[NSThread isMainThread] ? 1:0);

Comment: Did you verify that the activity indicator is actually non-`nil` and is actually in the view hierarchy? If the VC is popped, and then unloads and reloads its view, depending on how it gets the activity indicator I could imagine that it's now orphaned and not on a view hierarchy at all.

Comment: You could substitute with calls to `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From the best of my understanding, enumerateGroupsWithTypes is an asynchronous method, which means it runs on its own thread.

"Asynchronous" does not mean "runs on its own thread." There are several ways to be asynchronous in iOS. One of the most common is to use the run loop. This isn't to say that this method does not generate a thread; it might. But there's no reason to assume it does, and if it does, that's a private implementation detail. As you say, your block runs on the main thread and that's the only thing that should really concern you here.

From the symptom you describe, I doubt it has anything to do with this code. It sounds more like a mistake in your view loading code. I would be checking the routines `loadView`, `viewDidLoad`, `initWithFrame:`, `awakeFromNib`, `viewWillAppear:`, and `viewDidAppear:`. In all likelihood you are creating your progress indicator in the wrong place, or failing to insert it into the view hierarchy, or removing it from the view hierarchy.

Regarding simulating a slow loading time, I would recommend the "large number of pictures" approach. You should be able to generate a large number of pictures programmatically (you can even just duplicate the same picture over and over), so this shouldn't be too bad. A little annoying if it's your personal device, but such is the nature of development.

Comment: +1 Just for `"Asynchronous" does not mean "runs on its own thread."`. Not that the rest of your answer isn't right just I see this `async == different thread` logic all the time.